# Display XML generated from other website on my website as HTML

Tags: php, jquery, json, xml, html

I have serious problem with implementation of XML generated here http://www.profesia.sk/partner/export.php?auth=b1e4689c28cac5331a535e467bed3f3f on my own website. I'd like to display only `position` as `h3` and `content` as normal link. Is it even possible?

I am able to do only something like this:

```
<script>
    var xml = "<export><offer><offerdate>1.12.2015</offerdate><last_updated>2015-12-01 16:11:32</last_updated><position1><![CDATA[ Controller ]]></position1><location><![CDATA[ Ľudovíta Stárka 2150/16, Trenčín ]]></location><content><![CDATA[http://www.profesia.sk/partner/export.php?offer_id=2346292&auth=b1e4689c28cac5331a535e467bed3f3f&cdata=1]]></content><url><![CDATA[http://www.profesia.sk/praca/auto-kelly-slovakia/O2346292?statistics=626098_116&utm_campaign=offer&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=k_autokelly_1793]]></url><company><![CDATA[ AUTO KELLY SLOVAKIA, s.r.o. ]]></company><ico><![CDATA[ 36298026 ]]></ico></offer></export>",
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
        $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        $position = $xml.find( "position" ),
        $content = $xml.find( "content" );

        $( "#position" ).append( $position.text() );
        $( "#content" ).append( $content.text() );
</script>
```

and

```
<h3 id="position"></h3>
<a id="content"/>
```

So, my main problem is: How I can read that XML site dynamicaly?

Thank you.

Comment: That URL does not implement CORS so you will not be able to fetch it with JavaScript on your domain.  Download it in PHP, parse and output the HTML.

Comment: I know almost nothing about PHP. Could you help me somehow, at least what should I search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look in console, what kind of parameters did you got, so we see you get from xml an array, hier code example of your task:
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Your XML Links</h2>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var xml = '<export> <list count="2"> <offer id="2347893"> <offerdate value="2015-12-01">1.12.2015</offerdate> <last_updated>2015-12-01 16:11:32</last_updated> <position> <![CDATA[ Controller ]]> </position> <location> <![CDATA[ Ľudovta Strka 2150/16, Trenčn ]]> </location> <content> <![CDATA[ http://www.profesia.sk/partner/export.php?offer_id=2347893&auth=b1e4689c28cac5331a535e467bed3f3f&cdata=1 ]]> </content> <url> <![CDATA[ http://www.profesia.sk/praca/auto-kelly-slovakia/O2347893?statistics=626098_116&utm_campaign=offer&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=k_autokelly_1793 ]]> </url> <company> <![CDATA[ AUTO KELLY SLOVAKIA, s.r.o. ]]> </company> <ico> <![CDATA[ 36298026 ]]> </ico> <ref_nr/> <jobtypes> <jobtype>1</jobtype> </jobtypes> <offercategories> <offercategory id="2"> <![CDATA[ Ekonomika, financie, čtovnctvo ]]> </offercategory> </offercategories> <offerpositions> <offerposition id="161"> <![CDATA[ Controller ]]> </offerposition> <offerposition id="24"> <![CDATA[ Finančn analytik ]]> </offerposition> </offerpositions> <customfields></customfields> <offerregions> <offerregion id="409"> <![CDATA[ Trenčn ]]> </offerregion> </offerregions> </offer> <offer id="2332074"> <offerdate value="2015-11-18">18.11.2015</offerdate> <last_updated>2015-11-30 11:30:55</last_updated> <position> <![CDATA[ Obchodn zstupca - Trnava ]]> </position> <location> <![CDATA[ Trnava ]]> </location> <content> <![CDATA[ http://www.profesia.sk/partner/export.php?offer_id=2332074&auth=b1e4689c28cac5331a535e467bed3f3f&cdata=1 ]]> </content> <url> <![CDATA[ http://www.profesia.sk/praca/auto-kelly-slovakia/O2332074?statistics=626098_116&utm_campaign=offer&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=k_autokelly_1793 ]]> </url> <company> <![CDATA[ AUTO KELLY SLOVAKIA, s.r.o. ]]> </company> <ico> <![CDATA[ 36298026 ]]> </ico> <ref_nr/> <jobtypes> <jobtype>8</jobtype> </jobtypes> <offercategories> <offercategory id="10"> <![CDATA[ Obchod ]]> </offercategory> </offercategories> <offerpositions> <offerposition id="54"> <![CDATA[ Obchodn referent ]]> </offerposition> <offerposition id="56"> <![CDATA[ Obchodn zstupca ]]> </offerposition> <offerposition id="568"> <![CDATA[ Odborn predajca ]]> </offerposition> </offerpositions> <customfields></customfields> <offerregions> <offerregion id="507"> <![CDATA[ Trnava ]]> </offerregion> </offerregions> </offer> </list> </export>';

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml     = $( xmlDoc ),
  offer    = $xml.find( "offer " ),
  position = $xml.find( "position" ),
  content  = $xml.find( "content" );

var template = '';

for(var i=0, len=offer.length; i<len; i++){ 
   template += '<a id="content'+i+'" href="'+content[i].textContent+'">'
   template += '<h3 id="position'+i+'">'+position[i].textContent+'</h3>';
   template += '</a>';
}

$('.wrapper').append(template);
```

and if you want to change something in code for trying it, code is here http://plnkr.co/edit/vZEQImNkbkXJFwumGg8m?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, but i must work with this URL http://www.profesia.sk/partner/export.php?auth=b1e4689c28cac5331a535e467bed3f3f , because it will be changing. Is it possible or not?

Comment: use ajax $.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
});

Comment: And how should I put it into that code? All my possibilities have not worked.

Comment: Parse XML Cross-domain in javascript  not working, jquery ajax work good with jsonp, if you could parse your xml to json on server this should help, i give you link, some people have tried to work using jquery with  Parse XML Cross-domain, but don't sure that it is best solution : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

PHP code can be something like shown below

```
<?php
$xml = "<export><offer><offerdate>1.12.2015</offerdate><last_updated>2015-12-01 16:11:32</last_updated><position1><![CDATA[ Controller ]]></position1><location><![CDATA[ Ludovita Starka 2150/16, Trencin ]]></location><content><![CDATA[http://www.profesia.sk/partner/export.php?offer_id=2346292&auth=b1e4689c28cac5331a535e467bed3f3f&cdata=1]]></content><url><![CDATA[http://www.profesia.sk/praca/auto-kelly-slovakia/O2346292?statistics=626098_116&utm_campaign=offer&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=k_autokelly_1793]]></url><company><![CDATA[ AUTO KELLY SLOVAKIA, s.r.o. ]]></company><ico><![CDATA[ 36298026 ]]></ico></offer></export>";
$input = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo '<h3 id="position">'.$input->offer->company.'</h3>';
echo '<a id="content" href="'.$input->offer->content.'">'.$input->offer->position1.'</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how I can get `position` and `content` just right from http://www.profesia.sk/partner/export.php?auth=b1e4689c28cac5331a535e467bed3f3f ? There are about 5 posts containing `position` an `content` and it will be changing.
I have to be able to work with XML on that URL. Is there any possibility how to do it?